# celeryd-multi command unknown when using Django/djcelery

Tags: django, celery, djcelery

I'm using `Django` with `Celery` with the installed app `djcelery`. I'm trying to start multiple workers on the command line. I can run `python manage.py celeryd` without any issues. Everywhere, including [Celeryd Docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.1-archived/reference/celery.bin.celeryd_multi.html), says that the command is `celeryd-multi` to start multiple workers. I try to run `python manage.py celeryd-multi` and I get `Unknown command: 'celeryd-multi'`. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `python manage.py help` will show under the `djcelery` section a `celeryd_multi` option. The correct syntax is a `_` instead of `-` (this may just be when using `djcelery`). If you need more information use `python manage.py help celeryd_multi`.